# Oracle date time to datetime

Tags: oracle

I've looked at the answers on here but none of them seem to work.

I have the following date and time columns with example times how they are stored as below:

```
DATE_V      TIME_V
26-NOV-15   10:58
```

How do I add these together into one column and convert it to a datetime as below? The trailing zeros are not necessary.

```
DateTime_V
2015-11-26 10:58:00.000
```

I’ve used the following which saves it as string but I can't get it to datetime.

```
TO_CHAR(DATE_V, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' ' || TO_CHAR(TO_timestamp(time_V, 'HH24:MI'),'HH24:MI')

= 2015-11-26 10:58
```

Comment: Why are you storing the time as a separate column? Are you aware that an Oracle `DATE` _includes_ a time part?

Comment: What data type are the two columns? Oracle has neither a date-only data type nor a time-only one. Are these strings or what else?

Comment: so what a problem with using `to_date(your_expression, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming (bad word) that these are both stored as VARCHAR2 fields the following should work:

```
SELECT DATE_V, TIME_V, TO_DATE(DATE_V || ' ' || TIME_V, 'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI') AS DATETIME_V
  FROM YOURTABLE
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0901/2)

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.  The information is a system table and thats the way it came through.  I'll give your comment a go.